# Safe Browsing API v4. - Empty response

Tags: php, security, safe-browsing

I have implemented Safe Browsing API. I have domains that are declared as `phishing` domains. I have tested them and as the response I get empty array.

My question is, does google safe browsing API has type `PHISHING` anymore? I have fetched the safe browsing list but I have only find those types:

`MALWARE`,
`UNWANTED_SOFTWARE`,
`SOCIAL_ENGINEERING`,
`POTENCIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION`

Now I'm concerned because I can't test my domains on type **phishing**.

Does anyone knows anything about this?

Comment: I would assume that SOCIAL_ENGINEERING encompasses phishing …?

Comment: @CBroe can you tell me more about SOCIAL_ENGINEERING in the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Social engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security)) is a newer term for what people used to call phishing.

With phishing you think of the traditional e-mail that tries to lure someone onto a specific website, resp. a fake clone of it, to input their login credentials or perform certain actions.

Social engineering is a little broader, and includes other forms of getting people to perform certain actions – might be phone calls, etc. The main part is that the attacker uses information gathered about the person/company that make their request seem genuine. (F.e. employees wiring large amounts of money into foreign accounts because they thought it was their boss instructing them to do so is the kind of case that’s making headlines recently.)

So it looks like Google just change the name here, to better reflect what the category (Google calls it “threat types”) represents.